# Unable to serve static content with Jersey2.0

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm having trouble serving static content with jersey. I'm using Jersey 2.4.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <filter>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.nile.cardealer.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/static/jsp/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/static/(css|js).*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And my file structure under WEB-INF looks like:

WEB-INF

-static

--css

---main.css

--js

I'm unable to request main.css even though I have the jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex propery set. I've tried http://localhost:8084/CarDealer/static/css/main.css, http://localhost:8084/CarDealer/main.css and neither are able to retrieve the static resource. Other solutions on this site for similar problems haven't worked.

Comment: Keep the contents outside of  WEB-INF (but inside web content) folder and change path name accordingly in web.xml file

Comment: @Nithin, thank you, that fixed it. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I can upvote & accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally WEB-INF is a place for placing jars and deployment descriptor stub(web.xml).  Keep the contents outside of WEB-INF (but inside web content) folder and change path name accordingly in web.xml file.